# What does 'if (err)' tests precisely in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, null, undefined, instanceof

Many callback functions start by checking an `err` parameter as following:

```
function myCallback(err, result) {

    if ( err ) {

        // Handle error
        ...

    }

    ...

}
```

What does the `if (err)` test verifies? Does it check whether the object is `null`? Does it check whether it is `undefined`? Shouldn't one test for `instanceof Error`? When does this test return `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.js world, the callback functions have the following signature

```
function(error, result){}
```

If there is no error, then the `error` parameter is conventionally set to `null`, otherwise the corresponding error object.

So, the check `if (err)` checks if we really have an error situation or not. If the `err` object is `null`, then the check will fail (since `null` is falsy) otherwise the error handling code is executed.

> Shouldn't one test for instanceof Error?

It is not necessarily an instance of `Error` object. We can even pass an object literal as an error object or even an array representing array of errors.

> Does it check whether the object is null? Does it check whether it is undefined?

The test will evaluate to be falsy is the error object is either `null` or `undefined`.